# Subversion: How to preview a commit?

Tags: svn

Is there a way to list all files that will be modified, added, and deleted in my local copy, so I can sanity check before commit?

Comment: Use a client. TSVN for example, shows you with files have been modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed a good practice before each commit.

On Windows, you should go with *TortoiseSVN*.
Combined with compare tool (*Beyond Compare*, etc.) is your winner tool.

On Linux, you can use both

- `svn status` (or shorthand `svn st`) to see modified / deleted / added files
- and `svn diff <file>` to see changes.
  I use the following command to see differences in more nice form:
  `svn diff <file> | vim -`

Comment: there is a typo at (svn status). I tried sending an edit request, but the error message was: "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?" So I decided to comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TortoiseSVN the best way to do this is right click on your local copy. Select "**TortoiseSVN"--> "Check for modifications".**

This will give you the list of what you need.

If not, as someone suggested, use **svn status** on the command line.

This is give you what you are looking for....